# Urban Airship Adding a Notification Services does not work

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I'm trying to add a Notification Services for iOS.

I get no errors uploading the .p12 file and the password (I get agreen message: "App services have been saved!") but the iOS service stays grayed-out.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue. One of the error messages I noticed was when I went to write a test message, it told me I had a malformed certificate and that I should re-export and upload again. I actually removed the app entirely from UrbanAirship, re-exported the .p12 from my keychain and everything is working fine now.

Comment: I found the problem, I generated a new push certificate (.p12 to .pem) and it's work.
Thank you :)